# Optional Headers on Swagger Typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, swagger

I am creating a method that uses optional headers and if you make a request directly to the API works, but the swagger creates them as required.
I am using NestJS as a framework.

This is the code for the request on the controller:

```
  createShoppingCart(
    @Headers('authToken') authToken?: string ,
    @Headers('sessionToken') sessionToken?: string,
    @Headers('segmentToken') segmentToken?: string,
  ): Promise<GetCartInformationResponseDto> {
    return this.shoppingCartsService.createShoppingCart(
      authToken,
      sessionToken,
      segmentToken,
    );
  }
```

And this is how the swagger displays the Headers.
[image]

If I add the "or undefined" option it does not even show it into the swagger:

```
@Headers('authToken') authToken?: string | undefined,
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: this won't work because nestjs introspection doesn' know that `authToken` can be `undefined`. You'll need to use some of the `Api*` decorators to tell that `authToken` header is not required.

Comment: @MicaelLevi I cannot insert the "@Header()" decorator inside the "@ApiParameterOptional()" decorator. Can you show me what you meant?

Comment: `authToken` is not a path parameter, so there's no reason to use `@ApiParameterOptional` for that. Take a look at others `ApiX` decorators from `@nestjs/swagger`

Answer (score 1):

to make headers optional you can use `@ApiHeader()` decorator in your controller's route.

```
@Get()
@ApiHeader({
    name: 'x-skip-cache', // your header name
    required: false, // Set required to false to make it optional
    description: 'Optional header to skip cache',
  })
 async getLocationsData(
    @Headers('x-skip-cache') skipCache: string = 'false',
  ){}
```